# Relative Positioning of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is div named "dvUsers". there is an anchor tag "lnkUsers".

When one clicks on anchortag, the div must open like a popup div just below it.

Also the divs relative position should be maintained at window resize and all.
How to do that using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should look for a premade script like **overLIB**: http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/ !-)

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to place both of these inside of a parent div as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="lnkUsers" href="#">Users</a>
    <div id="dvUsers" style="display: none;">
        <!-- user content... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for these elements would be:

```
#container{
    /* ensure that #dvUsers is positioned relatively to this element */
    position: relative;
}
#dvUsers{
    position: absolute;
    /* this value should be based on the font-size of #lnkUsers */
    top: 30px;
    left: -10px;
}
```

This ensures that the div is positioned correctly relative to the link.  (For the sake of this question I am assuming the parent div is either "text-align: left" or floated)

The javascript would look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#lnkUsers').click(function(){
        $('#dvUsers').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#lnkUsers").click(function(){ $("#dvUser").show("slow"); });
```

style="display: none" should be applied to dvUser at the first place to make it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery plugin [PositionCalculator](https://github.com/tlindig/position-calculator).

HTML:

```
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link1</a></p>
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link 2</a></p>
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link 3</a></p>
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link 4</a></p>
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link 5</a></p>
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link 6</a></p>
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link 7</a></p>
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link 8</a></p>
  <p><a class="lnkUsers" href="javascript:void(0)">Users Link 9</a></p>

  <div id="dvUsers" style="display:none; position:absolute; padding:10px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); color:#ffffff">
    I am the popup. <b>Click me to close</b>
    <div class="dynamicInfo"></div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $popup = $('#dvUsers');
    var $infoField = $popup.find('.dynamicInfo');

    function showPopup(event) {

        // set content
        $infoField.text('clicked link: ' + $(this).text());

        // reset position
        $popup.show().css({top: 0, left: 0});

        // calculate new position
        var calculator = new $.PositionCalculator({
            item: $popup,
            itemAt: "top left",
            target: this,
            targetAt: "bottom left",
            flip: "both"
        });
        var posResult = calculator.calculate();

        // set new position
        $popup.css({
            top: posResult.moveBy.y + "px",
            left: posResult.moveBy.x + "px"
        });

        // window resize handler
        $(window).off('resize.dvUsers');
        $(window).on('resize.dvUsers', function(event) {
            $popup.css({top: 0, left: 0});
            var newResult = calculator.resize().calculate();
            $popup.css({
                top: newResult.moveBy.y + "px",
                left: newResult.moveBy.x + "px"
            });
        });
    }

    // add click handler for show and hide
    $('.lnkUsers').on('click', showPopup);
    $popup.on('click', function() {
        $popup.hide();
        $(window).off('resize.dvUsers');
    });
});
```

Here is the [example at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kefux/1/edit?html,js,output)